# Spring Data MongoDB add common criteria

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using Spring Data MongoDB repository abstraction to access mongoDB database:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<Customer, String> {}
```

...

```
@Autowired
private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

List<Customer> customers = customerRepository.findAll();
```

this will fetch all customers from mongoDB collection.

I'd like to add criteria for **all** CustomerRepository methods to filter customers by`{"active": true}` (the actual filter is more complicated if it's matter) transparently (without changing interface).

I'm thinking about overriding some base Spring Data MongoDB classes but I'm not sure how to do it.

Thanks.